# Como puedo crear elementos html ya sea con canvas o DOM

Tags: javascript, html5, dom, canvas, elementos

Buen dia, tengo la siguiente situacion deseo hacer un menu lateral digamos donde yo muestre los elementos basicos de html un input,select,textarea,etc.
con la idea de que el usuario los pueda arrastrar y a comodar como el lo desee
no se si tenga alguna sugerencia como hacerlo o que puedo investigar que se lo mas conveniente

Comment: No se como funciona *canvas*, pero me parece que no es una opción si quieres crear elementos HTML de un formulario funcionales. Si quieres crear elementos variados y dar también la posibilidad de colocarlos necesitas un montón de JS. Puedes partir de un menú de elementos y de varias cajas (cuadrícula) donde colocarlos.
Si cada elemento se va a usar una vez, se podría arrastrar directamente. Para poder crear un elemento mas veces, un botón asignado a cada uno para crear el elemento que vas a arrastrar.

Comment: Orici Gracias por tu comentario lo tomare en cuenta igual si me estoy inclinando por el DOM por que como tu lo comentas voy a requerir mucho JS